# Is it possible to compile python interpreter to static single exe (with eventual one dll or so) with most used packages?

Tags: python

I don't mean to compile code and interpreter as an exe as it is 99% questions there. I mean to build a static single python.exe to be able to execute any script by giving it as argument any *.py file.

I mean the same situation as it is with nodeJS when you download only single executable.

Or if it is not possible to single exe, maybe to just a few files instead of huge default package such as is with for example Sublime text where all python engine is in python33.dll and python3.3.zip all about 5mb, but there is no python exe to run code externally that is not as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you need three files. You question lists two of them. The third is `python.exe`. On Windows the interpreter *must* be built separately from the actual executable so that C modules can access the functions within the interpreter.

The DLL must be built from the Python source so that all the C modules that come with Python can be built into it instead of being contained in the .pyd files that come with Python. The zip file is composed of all the Python modules in the standard library; see the [`zipimport`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html) documentation for more information about the import process.

Comment: Yes, but from where I get these files (for example for the new v.3.4) ? Original python download has python3.dll that is a very small file not near 2 mb that sublime text has, and there is no python.zip.

Comment: The .zip file can be created by zipping up the modules that come with Python.